# PHP Erro PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' ao fazer um foreach de array

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com problemas em fazer um foreach de array, está apresentando erro, segue o código abaixo:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Código</th>
<th>Produto</th>
<th>Valor</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($dado_produto = $result_produtos->fetch_array()){ ?>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado_produto['descricao']; ?></td>
<td><input type = "text" name="valor[<?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?>]"/>
<input type = "hidden" name="linha[<?php echo $dado_produto['linha']; ?>]"/>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
</div> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

O **valor.php** recebe os valores pelo method POST

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include_once("../../controle/conexao.php");
// Início da consulta
$sql = "INSERT INTO `produtos` (`cod`, `valor`, `linha`) VALUES";

// Para cada elemento produto:
foreach($_POST['valor'] as $cod=>$val; $_POST['linha'] as $linha){

// Monta a parte consulta de cada produto
$sql .= " ('{$produto}', '{$valor}', '{$linha}'),";}

// Tira o último caractere (vírgula extra)
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

// Executa a consulta
mysqli_query($sql);
$cadastrados = mysqli_affected_rows();
?>
```

Mas está me retornando o erro

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

A linha que ocorre o erro é:

> foreach($_POST['valor'] as $cod=>$val; $_POST['linha'] as $linha){

já troquei por virgula mas ainda continua dando erro, esse código peguei de um site na web como de referencia, mas pelo visto está incorreto. Qual seria método correto?

Comment: Você está tentando fazer o `foreach` em dois arrays ao mesmo tempo? Acredito que isso não seja possível desta maneira.

Comment: Verifique a forma correta de fazer um [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) a maneira que está.... está gerando erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa sintaxe esta totalmente errada:

```
foreach($_POST['valor'] as $cod=>$val; $_POST['linha'] as $linha){
```

Conforme a doc a sintaxe é somente isto:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

Não se usa duas expressões ao mesmo tempo, o `;` inesperado provavelmente é o de dentro do `foreach`

Outro problema é que tua query tem 4 `values`:

```
$sql .= " (1, '{$produto}', '{$valor}', '{$linha}'),";}
```

Mas só esta chamando 3 colunas no insert:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `produtos` (`cod`, `valor`, `linha`) VALUES";
```

O mysql vai disparar um erro assim

### Resolvendo a iteração

Para ser sincero não consegui entender muito bem o sentido do código, mas creio que se o objectivo é inserir um valor para cada produto você possa mudar o HTML para isto:

```
<td><?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado_produto['descricao']; ?></td>
<td>

    <input type="hidden" name="novo_valor[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cod[]" value="<?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="linha[]" value="<?php echo $dado_produto['linha']; ?>"/>
</td>
```

E o `for` ficaria assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `produtos` (`cod`, `valor`, `linha`) VALUES";

$novos_valores = $_POST['novo_valor'];

// Para cada elemento produto:
for ($i = 0; $i < count($novos_valores); $i++){

    $novo_valor = $novos_valores[$i];
    $linha = $_POST['linha'][$i];
    $cod = $_POST['cod'][$i];

    // Monta a parte consulta de cada produto
    $sql .= " ('{$cod}', '{$novo_valor}', '{$linha}'),";
}

//IMPORTANTE: o mysql_query tem que ficar fora do `for`

// Tira o último caractere (vírgula extra)
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);

// Executa a consulta
mysqli_query($sql);
$cadastrados = mysqli_affected_rows();
```

> **nota:** da maneira que esta o teu código pode sofre ataques de SqlInjection recomendo trocar a abordagem por [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Junior vou arriscar um palpite então, mas realmente espero que seja só isto, caso contrário e não for eu vou fechar a pergunta até que você explicado melhor o objetivo (edite a sua pergunta), não leve a mal ok? Espera só um pouco que vou editar a minha resposta e você vê se isto resolve

Comment: levo não, que a gente acha muita porcaria na internet e difícil aprender sozinho.. com tanta coisa ruim

Comment: Cadastrando múltiplos registros no MySQL ao mesmo tempo, esse é objetivo esse código eu tirei do http://blog.thiagobelem.net/cadastrando-multiplos-registros-no-mysql-ao-mesmo-tempo, e outro achei no forum imaster.

Comment: @Junior editei novamente, veja se consegue entender.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta e pela dica do SqlInjection :)

Comment: vê se pode me ajudar, agora se eu quiser fazer update é a mesma logica ?

Comment: Complementando. Não deixe de verificar se foram informados os campos obrigatórios. Muitas vezes pode ocorrer de um campo vir vazio etc